# Trying to compile and receiving the following errors, undefined references to certain classes.

Tags: c++

These are the errors that have occured when trying to compile the file main.cpp:

```
 C:\Users\student\Desktop\C++ Solution Framework (1)\AssignmentSolution\AssignmentSolution\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to   `MsgPacket::MsgPacket(int, int, int, int, std::string)'|
 C:\Users\student\Desktop\C++ Solution Framework (1)\Assignment Solution\AssignmentSolution\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `DataStream::DataStream()'|
 ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|
```

This is the main.cpp file itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "DataStream.h"
#include "MsgPacket.h"


using namespace std;

DataStream * Packet = new DataStream();
DataStream::DataStream();



int main() {

int source;
int destination;
int type;
int port;
int input;
std::string data;

cout << "My Assignment" << endl;;


MsgPacket * Packet = new MsgPacket(source,destination,type,port,data);
}
```

This is the MsgPacket.h

```
#ifndef MSGPACKET_H
#define MSGPACKET_H

#include <string>
#include "PacketAddress.h"

using namespace std;

class MsgPacket : public PacketAddress {
public:
    MsgPacket();
    MsgPacket (const MsgPacket & rhs);
    MsgPacket(string dataIn);
    MsgPacket(int source, int destination, int port, int type, std::string data);
    MsgPacket(int ,char data);
    string toString();
    string getData() const {return _data;};
    void setData(string inData) {_data = inData;};
    string dataOutput();
    virtual ~MsgPacket();
    virtual MsgPacket * Clone() { return new MsgPacket(*this); }
protected:
    string _data;
};

#endif // MSGPACKET_H
```

And finally this is the MsgPacket.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "msgpacket.h"


using namespace std;

MsgPacket::MsgPacket():
PacketAddress(0,0)
{

}

MsgPacket::MsgPacket (const MsgPacket & rhs):
PacketAddress(rhs),
_data(rhs.getData())
{

}

MsgPacket::MsgPacket(string dataIn):
PacketAddress(0,0){
string temp;
temp = dataIn.substr (0,4);
_source = atoi(temp.c_str());
temp = dataIn.substr (5,4);
_dest = atoi(temp.c_str());
temp = dataIn.substr (10,4);
_type = atoi(temp.c_str());
temp = dataIn.substr (15,4);
_port = atoi(temp.c_str());
_data = dataIn.substr (20,dataIn.length());
#ifdef DEBUG
cout << "CREATE PACKET: " << this->toString() << endl;
#endif
}

MsgPacket::MsgPacket(int source, int destination):
PacketAddress(source,destination)
{

 }

 MsgPacket::MsgPacket(int source, int destination, int port):
PacketAddress(source,destination)
{
 _port = port;
}

 MsgPacket::MsgPacket(int source, int destination, int type, int port, std::string       data):
 PacketAddress(source, destination)
{
_source = source;
_dest = destination;
_type = type;
_data = data;
_port = port;
}

string MsgPacket::dataOutput()
{
stringstream output;//create a stringstream
output << setw(4) << setfill('0') << _source << ":" <<  setw(4) << setfill('0') <<  _dest << ":" << setw(4) << setfill('0') << _type << ":" << setw(4) << setfill('0') << _port     << ":" << _data;
 return output.str();
}

 string MsgPacket::toString()
{
stringstream output;//create a stringstream
output << "[" << showbase << hex << this  << "] S:[" << _source << "] D:[" << _dest << "] P:[" << _type << "] T:[" << _port << "]" << " DATA[" << _data << "]";
return output.str();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but why are you using `using namespace std` and then qualifying std::string? just curious. Also putting a using declaration is very dangerous in a header file

Comment: Further, in your constructor, you call the base class constructor, but then set its (im assuming) members again in the body of your constructor

Comment: Also your PacketAddress only accepts a source and destination, but your MsgPacket has no port data member.

Comment: and this is not defined as well `DataStream::DataStream();` it needs `{...stuff..here...}`

Answer (score 3):

`Undefined reference to` means that you're trying to refer to something that cannot be linked.  Are you linking your two cpp files together?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get them to link together

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is working. The linker is having trouble finding the definition of that constructor for some reason. I don't see a constructor at all for the `DataStream`. Sometimes a failed link is caused by the functions you wrote being ever so slightly different, making entirely different functions compared to the prototypes. But they look the same to me in this case.